# Selenium C# - how can i implement click on button without button name and id

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

How can i write test scripts for login button without button name and id?
Here my code,

```
<button _ngcontent-lcu-6="" class="md-primary pull-right" md-raised-button="">
    <span class="md-button-wrapper">Login</span>
    <div class="md-button-ripple" md-ripple="" mdripplebackgroundcolor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)">
    <div class="md-ripple-background"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="md-button-focus-overlay"></div>
    </button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XPath or CSS to locate an element when there is no ID or name associated with a target element.

**XPATH**

```
//button/span[text()='Login']
```

**CSS**

```
 button>span.md-button-wrapper
```

Sample code

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button/span[text()='Login']")).Click();

driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button>span.md-button-wrapper")).Click();
```

Comment: I think this answer is missing Protractor :p